# Getting AccessDenied when trying to download rundeck deb package

Tags: rundeck

I was trying to download the deb package from windows and ubuntu uring URL https://docs.rundeck.com/download/deb/ and getting access denied. What could be the reason?
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

That link is outdated, use [this](https://www.rundeck.com/community-downloads) one.